How do I send a get request using oauth?
I am trying to connect to the Arduino cloud API via app, but I'm getting constant errors.
The errors that I get:

Line 17: Extra arguments at positions #2, #3 in call
Line 22: Missing argument for parameter 'connectionHandler' in call
Line 28: Expressions are not allowed at the top level

This is the code that I've tried:
import OAuthSwift
import Foundation

class ArduinoCloudAPI {
    private let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    "***",
        consumerSecret: "***",
        authorizeUrl:   "",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://api2.arduino.cc/iot/v1/clients/token",
        responseType:   "token"
    )
    
    func authenticateAndFetchProperties(thingId: String) {
        oauthswift.client.credential.oauthToken = "your_saved_access_token"  // If you already have a token saved
        let propertiesUrl = "https://api2.arduino.cc/iot/v1/things/\(thingId)/properties"
        
        oauthswift.client.get(propertiesUrl, success: { response in
            let dataString = response.string ?? "Failed to get data"
            print(dataString)
        }, failure: { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        })
    }
}

// Usage
let arduinoAPI = ArduinoCloudAPI()
arduinoAPI.authenticateAndFetchProperties(thingId: "9224968a-5263-4f3a-b552-94a2f3dfa69e")

This is what I found online but it doesn't work. How do I get the app to connect to the Arduino cloud using an API?

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is OAuthSwift? Which are lines 17, 22, and 28?

Is this code in a Swift Playground or in the code of a regular project? Unless this is a Playground, you can't have code outside of a function like you do for those last two lines.
